# Functional analysis, calculus

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(S,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space and $(T_{t})_{t>0}$ be a family of bounded operators such that

1. $D(T)=L^{2}(S;\mu)$, $T:D(T)\to L^{2}(S;\mu)$
2. ${}^{\forall}f \in L^{2}(S;\mu)$, $\|T_{t}f-f\|_{L^{2}(S;\mu)}\to 0$ as $t \to0$
3. $\|T_{t}\|_{L^{2}(S;\mu)}\leq 1$
4. ${}^{\forall}t>0, {}^{\forall} f \in L^{2}(S;\mu)$ with $0 \leq f \leq1$,  $0 \leq T_{t}f \leq1$

In the above case, **the following my computation is true?**

$A,B \in \Sigma$ with $\mu(A),\mu(B)<\infty$:fix ($1_{A},1_{B} \in L^{2}(S;\mu)$)

By condition (2.)

\begin{align*}
F(t):=\int_{S}1_{A} T_{t}1_{B} d \mu \to \int_{S}1_{A}1_{B} d\mu=\mu(A \cap B) \quad {\rm as} \,t \to 0 
\end{align*}

Therefore $\displaystyle \log(F(t))\to\log(\mu(A \cap B))$ as $t \to 0$ and $t \log( F(t)) \to 0$ as $t \to 0$

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's true but you need a justification for the first computation. It's not so difficult, you just need to use a triangle inequality and Cauchy-Schwarz.

$\begin{align*}
|F(t)-\int_S 1_AT_t1_Bd\mu| &\leq \int_S 1_A|T_t1_B - 1_B|d\mu \\
                     &\leq \|1_A\|_{L^{2}(S;\mu)}\|T_t1_B-1_B\|_{L^{2}(S;\mu)} \\
                     &\leq \mu(A)^{1/2}\|T_t1_B-1_B\|_{L^{2}(S;\mu)} \to 0
\end{align*}$

The last two limit are straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understood.